# Is there an Alpha matcher for .NET Regex?

Tags: .net, regex

The usual alpha symbol for regular expressions `\w` in the .NET Framework matches alphanumeric symbols, and thus is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, right? There is any `[a-zA-Z]` equivalent in .NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite, `\w` also matches the underscore and accented characters (ä, ó, etc.).

If you just want to match letters (including accented ones), you can use the Unicode property `\p{L}`

Comment: Here's a link to all the character classes in .NET Regex in great detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter):

> If ECMAScript-compliant behavior is specified, \w is equivalent to [a-zA-Z_0-9]. For information on ECMAScript regular expressions, see Regular Expression Options and ECMAScript vs. Canonical Matching Behavior.

So if you use

```
new Regex("\w", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

It will be equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`